# How was my phone cloned or mirrored by my roommate and how do i get evidence to prove it and shut her down. I believe she used a usb-c port hook up

Tags: laptop, wifi, bluetooth, usb-c, remote-control

It's like everything I go through in life is instantly on facebook or a social media platform. Being made fun of in some way plus passwords change within seconds of logging in when I try to logout just a slight change is made.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear the troubles you're going through. You have asked this question on the wrong site though, we do product purchase recommendations here and not tech support. I think this might be slightly on-topic for [superuser](https://superuser.com)

Comment: If someone has access to your email account, they can use it to reset passwords on other accounts.